# python difference between (x is not None) and (y is not None) and (x and y) is not None

Tags: python

The following conditions give the same results. Are there any performance (or any other) differences between them ?

1.

```
if (x != None) and (y != None):
    # Proceed
```

2.

```
if (x and y) is not None:
    # Proceed
```

Comment: if x and y: is enough

Comment: @glasslion No, try `x=0` and `y=0` for example

Comment: @glasslion In my case I am specifically dealing with integers where `0` is also an option so I specifically need to check for `None` as I wand the condition to pass if either is `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A programmer's wife asks him: do you want sausage or bacon for breakfast? - Yes, he responds. *(a true story).*

When using boolean constructs in everyday speaking we tend to skip common parts so that `X(Y) @ X(Z)` becomes `X @ (Y,Z)`:

```
Her bunny is happy and her hamster is happy (1)
```

is the same as

```
Her bunny and her hamster are happy
```

In programming, however, we cannot contract things like that. The first statement

```
bunny == happy and hamster == happy
```

will be true if both pets are fine. The second phrase translates literally to this:

```
(bunny and hamster) == happy
```

here, `(bunny and hamster)` evaluates to

```
- a falsy value, if she's got no bunny
- the hamster otherwise
```

So `(bunny and hamster) == happy` actually reads as:

```
She's got a bunny and her hamster is happy
```

which is quite different from the statement (1)

In python:

```
>>> happy = 1
>>> sad = 2
>>> bunny = sad
>>> hamster = happy
>>> bunny == happy and hamster == happy
False
>>> (bunny and hamster) == happy
True
>>>
```

Comment: Good thing the wife didn't ask, "Is it just me or do these jeans make me look fat." :)

Answer (score 9):

```
In [44]: x = False

In [45]: y = None

In [46]: (x != None) and (y != None)
Out[46]: False

In [47]: (x and y) is not None
Out[47]: True
```

---

By the way, when testing if something is None, it is better to test

```
if x is None
```

rather than

```
if x == None
```

The result can be different:

```
class Egalitarian(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

x = Egalitarian()

print(x == None)
# True

print(x is None)
# False
```

Comment: I am sorry, this does not answer the question, the OP is trying to understand compound if statements, and how using multiple conditions work.

Comment: Well it does point out that the OPs two "solutions" are actually not equivalent ...

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand what it is you are doing to understand the *real* differences, you might think the following is a simple statement:

```
>>> if (x and y) is not None:
```

It is not a simple conditional statement. Here, you are first evaluating `(x and y)` which will return the last *Truthy* value it finds, or the first *Falsey* value it finds, and then compare that to `is not None`. Which will yield sometimes unexpected results. (Consult [The Peculiar Nature of `and` and `or`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html))

If you want to check to make sure that *both* `x` and `y` are not `None` you should do something like the following:

```
>>> if all(var is not None for var in [x, y]):
```

Which is almost the same as:

```
>>> if x is not None and y is not None:
```

Only a bit easier to read, and more robust (if you add more variables to check),

---

Either way, the difference between your two statements are that the first one will actually do what you expect, but you *should* be using `is not` instead of `!=` when it comes to `None`. And the second statement might work sometimes, but is doing something that you probably were not expecting.

Comment: Not really. If `x=None` and `y=None`, then `(x and y) is None` will evaluate to `True`

Comment: No, try it. `(x and y) is not None` is False if both x and y are None

Comment: @InbarRose if x=0 and y=0 then `(x and y)` evaluates to `0` not `true` or `false` :/

Comment: `(x and y)` will return the first Truthy statement, and compare that to `None` it is not doing what you want.

Comment: Matter of fact seems like `(x and y)` never evaluates to `true/false` until either x or y is a boolean itself.

Comment: @JanneKarila you are right, I corrected my wording, "will return the last Truthy value it finds, or the first Falsey value it finds"

Answer (score 0):

Usually

```
if x and y:
    #Proceed
```

is good enough in the Python world.

Here I says good enough because in most cases a function should not return False and None while they have different meanings in the function logic.

For those downvoters, seriously will you write the following codes in real world?

```
if x is None:
    #xxx
elif x == False:
    #xxxx
else:
    #xxx
```

I just want to point out that the both  example are not pythonic and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

"is" and "is not" are fast as they check identity (i.e. comparing pointers/references)

The other comparisons and logical operators will inspect the object's values (or truthiness).

Generally to check for "None" values, you therefore want to use "is"/"is not".

Personally I find that relying on the behaviour of None values in an expression is bad form (things that would often trigger NullPointerException or similar errors in many other languages), so while I'm not completely sure what is you are trying to achieve, generally similar code I write looks like:

```
if x is not None and y is not None:
```